# Add one in a number of arraylist

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {

    public ArrayList<Integer> plusOne(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
        int n = A.size(); 

        // Add 1 to last digit and find carry 
        A.set(n - 1, A.get(n - 1) + 1); 
        int carry = A.get(n - 1) / 10; 
        A.set(n - 1, A.get(n - 1) % 10); 

        // Traverse from second last digit 
        for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) { 
            if (carry == 1) { 
                A.set(i, A.get(i) + 1); 
                carry = A.get(i) / 10; 
                A.set(i, A.get(i) % 10); 
            } 
        } 

        // If carry is 1, we need to add 
        // a 1 at the beginning of vector 
        if (carry == 1) 
            A.add(0, 1);

        return A;
    }
}
```

Question is:

Given a non-negative number represented as an array of digits,

add 1 to the number ( increment the number represented by the digits ).

The digits are stored such that the most significant digit is at the head of the list.

Example:

If the vector has [1, 2, 3]

the returned vector should be [1, 2, 4]

as 123 + 1 = 124.
Wrong Answer. Your program's output doesn't match the expected output. You can try testing your code with custom input and try putting debug statements in your code.

Your submission failed for the following input:
A : [ 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 0, 9, 6, 5, 1 ]

Your function returned the following :
0 4 4 6 0 9 6 5 2

The expected returned value :
4 4 6 0 9 6 5 2

Comment: you just need to remove zeros on first positions

Comment: @AkashDubey but how

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)

Comment: This feels like homework.... Also you do not pose a real question here?

Comment: @SBylemans it's not homework why do you think its homework? we ask the questions here if we stuck at some point without knowing reason do not downvote

Comment: @VishweshSoni It feels like you copied the question and the example from somewhere, along with the 'Wrong answer' part. If it is not homework, like a challenge of some sort you're trying to solve, give us the source... And as stated earlier, there's no real question asked here? You already seem to know what to do: remove the zero's, but instead of asking: How do I remove leading zero's from `ArrayList`? you seem to paste a task from somewhere. Just trying to help out how you should ask a question, not trying to antagonize you....

Answer (score -1):

Use below method

```
private ArrayList<Integer> recursiveCheckZero() {
    if (arrayList.get(0) == 0) {
        arrayList.remove(0);
        recursiveCheckZero();
    } else {
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

This method will be used to zero at first position, it would be called recursively until all zeros get removed. and when there will be no zero at first position it will return final ArrayList of integers as actual result

Comment: Most likely, it got downvoted because of nearly no information added to the code. While the code might solve the problem, it does neither explain where to put or use it, nor how it provides an answer to the question. Just add more information to your answer. Lack of textual information is obviously a main reason for downvoting answers.

Comment: @deHaar is it enough now!!

Comment: I was just confirming that, is it enough just for the sake of betterment!!, I am not assuming you is the one!

Answer (score -1):

```
int sum=0;
int carry=0;
int i=0;
while (i < A.size() - 1 && A.get(i) == 0) {
         A.remove(i);  //remove all zeroes in front
 }
for(i=A.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
 {
    int n=A.get(i);
    sum=n+carry;
    if(i==A.size()-1)
           {
              sum = sum+1;
                    
          }
     carry=sum/10;
      sum=sum%10;
     A.set(i,sum);
}
            
            if (carry !=0)
                A.add(0,1);
            return A;
```

Comment: Can you please explain your solution a bit?